# Python - connecting sockets, client/server agnostic

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I want 2 processes to communicate on a given port without either one having a defined client or server role. Either of the processes may be running alone. Either may stop and restart at any time, in any order. When they are both running they need to communicate (when only one is running, communication is just discarded).

I want non-blocking sockets and Windows/Linux support.

Comment: That code doesn't look anything like Python. Do you mean that that's pseudocode?

Comment: It's very rough pseudocode...

Comment: Okay so I want to down-vote this question here's why: A.) it isn't even phrased as a question. B.) you obviously have not even tried to find an  answer for yourself (or, you are horrible at using google, which is something to be ashamed of and to rectify) C.) the questions that are actually questions are not really questions(like they are literal questions but they lack any sense of "I couldn't figure this out- or I've tried to do X why can't I."). please don't take this criticism as cruel or sadistically punitive. -sorry for any misspellings and whatnot.

Comment: You're right, I just lazily wrote this question before trying to solve it, thinking someone else must have solved it already. (Couldn't find solution on google.). At any rate, I've posted my own solution now.

Comment: Would UDP (aka SOCK_DGRAM instead of SOCK_STREAM) be a possibility for this application?  Just have process A receive on UDP port (n), and process B receive on UDP port (n+1), and have each send to the other's UDP port.  This would give you most of the qualities you want, plus packetization as well; the only downside would be the possibility of occasionally losing a packet (unusual over localhost but not impossible), so your app would have to account for that.

Comment: Reliability is quite important when the two are both running (when the second one starts, they send messages to share current state, and all future messages are too maintain it). So I don't think I want to deal with UDP, unless it might be easier for this purpose (I've never really worked with it tbh...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather crude class that actually works to some extent, which might get you started.

The main trick here is not to bother with `listen` at all: these are pure peer to peer connections, fully specified by the <local-addr, remote-addr> pair.

Note that the sockets are left in non-blocking mode.  I caught the `recv` exception but there can be a `send` one as well (plus, you get broken-pipe errors when sending to a dead peer, etc).  You'll also need to handle EOF-from-terminated-peer (when `recv` returns `''` instead of failing with `EAGAIN`).

```
import errno
import os
import select
import socket

class Peer(object):
    def __init__(self, local_addr, peer_addr):
        self._local_addr = local_addr
        self._peer_addr = peer_addr
        self._renew()
        self.reopen()

    def _renew(self):
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._sock.bind(self._local_addr)
        self._sock.setblocking(False)
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._state = 'bound'

    def is_open(self):
        return self._state == 'open'

    def is_opening(self):
        return self._state == 'opening'

    def reopen(self):
        if self._state == 'open':
            raise ValueError('already open')
        if self._state == 'opening':
            raise ValueError('open in progress')
        print 'try connect to:', self._peer_addr
        error = self._sock.connect_ex(self._peer_addr)
        print 'result:', error
        if error == 0:
            self._state = 'open'
            print 'connected immediately'
        elif error in (errno.EINPROGRESS, errno.EINTR):
            self._state = 'opening'
            print 'connection in progress'
        else:
            raise socket.error(error, os.strerror(error))

    def _check_open(self):
        if self._state != 'opening':
            raise ValueError('improper call to _check_open')
        print 'check connect to:', self._peer_addr
        _, wfds, _ = select.select([], [self._sock], [])
        if len(wfds) == 0:
            # connection still in progress
            return
        # we have a result: fail or succeed, either way a result
        try:
            peer = self._sock.getpeername()
        except socket.error as err:
            print 'caught err:', err
            if err.errno == errno.ENOTCONN:
                print 'connection failed, no peer available'
                self.close()
                return
            raise
        print 'got a peer:', peer
        self._state = 'open'
        print 'connection finished'

    def close(self):
        if self._state in ('open', 'opening'):
            self._sock.close()
            self._renew()
            # self.reopen() - or leave to caller

    def send_if_connected(self, data):
        # to do: add check for send to dead peer, and if so, _renew etc
        if self._state == 'bound':
            self.reopen()
        if self._state == 'opening':
            self._check_open()
        if self._state == 'open':
            self._sock.send(data)

    def recv_if_connected(self):
        # to do: add check for send to dead peer, and if so, _renew etc
        if self._state == 'bound':
            self.reopen()
        if self._state == 'opening':
            self._check_open()
        if self._state == 'open':
            try:
                return self._sock.recv(1024)
            except socket.error as err:
                # still connected but no data avail
                if err.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
                    return ''
                raise
        else:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    import time

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test Peer()')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--localhost', default='')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=9001)
    parser.add_argument('-R', '--remote-host', default='')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--remote-port', type=int, default=9002)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    x = Peer((args.localhost, args.port), (args.remote_host, args.remote_port))
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print 'attempt to send %d' % i
        x.send_if_connected('send %d' % i)
        got = x.recv_if_connected()
        if got is not None:
            print 'got: "%s"' % got
        time.sleep(1)
```

Run with: `$ python peerish.py -p 9001 -r 9002 & python peerish.py -p 9002 -r 9001 &` for instance.

Comment: This has issues with synchronization: if the two connect() attempts do not fire off at nearly the same time, the peers don't hook up properly.  Not sure how to fix this other than resorting to an actual listener socket.